# android - Converting textual String to date, but multiple possible formats?

Tags: java, android, sql, date

I am trying to convert a String the user entered into an EditText into the date format "dd-MM-yyyy".

I know I can just use SimpleDateFormat to help me, but that requires a **fixed format**, but what the user should be able to do is to enter the date in **any format he likes** and the app will just convert it into the date format.

For example, today is the 25th of June 2014, and if the user inputs "friday" that app will convert that into 27-06-2014. Or let's say the user inputs "2/7", "02/07", "2/07", "02/07/2014", "2/7/14", "2/7/2014", "2.7.14", "02 07 2014", "2 7 14", "next wednesday", "next wed", "next week wednesday" and so on, the date will still be "02-07-2014".

Also, we can assume that the **date** is always inputted before the **month**, if not this would not be possible because obviously the app couldn't know.

Of course, if the user uses a ridiculous format no one knows, the app will simply output "I didn't understand you" as a Toast.

The problem I have is that there are **SO MANY FORMATS!** So should I find and check for every single format and try to convert them, or maybe is there a more efficient and easy way to do this? Or maybe there is a library out there I can use for this, or even a class already written so I don't have to. I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: use a datepicker dialog instead. Who wants to type all the date??

Comment: Good point, but typing "friday" really fast especially if you have a swipe keyboard. And I wanna know if this was even possible

Comment: Day/month/year seems like a pretty unconventional format.

Comment: @user3032282 without any kind of restriction it is not possible consider 03/04/2014 how are going to know if it is 3rd april 2014 or 4th march 2014. Also typing in reqular keyboard(desktop) is fast but is a small screen of mobiles I dont think that any keyboard can be that fast

Comment: @shmosel Its the format usually used in Europe

Comment: @Illegal Argument just assume the day is always before the month

Comment: @IllegalArgument it gets worse-  3/4/12.  Which is the month, day, and year?

Comment: @user3032282 I wouldn't do that-  Americans always go month/day/year.

Comment: @GabeSechan you are right there's no solution

Comment: ya, GabeSechan and IllegalArgument both are right, as per user friendly app, you have to use datepicker dialog instead of your's.